# Comparing Int to Double - No Warning?

Tags: scala, equality

Given the following case classes:

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> case class Bar(x: Int)
defined class Bar
```

The compiler shows a warning when trying to compare instances of different case classes.

```
scala> Foo(5) == Bar(5)
<console>:15: warning: comparing case class values of types Foo and Bar using `==' will always yield false
       Foo(5) == Bar(5)
              ^
res8: Boolean = false
```

But why doesn't the following comparison give a warning?

```
scala> (5 : Int) == (10 : Double)
res9: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `==` is an overloaded method for `Int`, one of which accepts `Double` as an argument type (the same goes for `Double`, and many others). This is 100% legal.

```
abstract def ==(x: Double): Boolean
```

See the [scaladocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int@==(x:Double):Boolean).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for `res8: Boolean = false` is because you are comparing the instances of the objects `Foo and Bar` by comparing `Foo(5) == Bar(5)`, as the address of the instances will always different and the `false` result is obvious with the warning. And the `==` method will always converts the arguments to double before validating.

Try like this

```
    case class Foo(x: Int)
    case class Bar(x: Double)

    val a = Foo(5)
    val b = Bar(5)

    a.x == b.x //res4: Boolean = true
    a == b //res5: Boolean = false
```